# mozilla firefox, deploy credentials (user,password) for a specific web site

Tags: firefox, password-management, deployment

We have many client PCs with firefox 45.8 ESR.

We cannot give the credentials (user,password) of this web site to end-users.

Is it possible using files ... settings ... policies to preload the credentials ?

In other words, to mimic the operator "save this credentials ? : YES" at the first manual login.

Note: we cannot skip the website login or change its functionality, server side

Comment: Are the credentials domain credentials, the same the PC is logged into as?

Comment: good question. no, they aren't linked to internal user accounts. we have only one set of credentials, to share between all the users.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, if you cannot "give" the credentials to the end users, then you are out of luck. Firefox operates within the user's account, and all information it has access to the user also has access to.

Any saved credentials pre-configured in Firefox will be visible and accessible to your users.

So if that is your security requirement, you are out of luck.

Comment: ok, with bare-bone ff. any suggestion about a minimal features, not bloated, addon ?

Comment: No. Any plugin-based features will have the same drawback: They'll work within the user's context, and any information they have will be information the user can retrieve. Your two requirements: Unable to change the server and unable to share the credentials, are at odds with each other and cannot both be satisfied. Either you create a user account with limited-enough permissions that sharing it is not a threat, or you use alternative authentication or access validation methods on the server itself. Perhaps a security certificate issued to each client.

Comment: we cannot change the server and login behaviour. the plugin can allow to programmatically pre-load the credentials (example from file), but don't show them to the users. for us a similar solution is fine, we aren't fighting hackers.

Comment: You do not appear to understand two things: 1, If you assume you're not fighting hackers, you're assuming wrong, and you shouldn't be allowed anywhere near a system with an administrator role, and 2, there is no way to pass credentials through a browser that does not make them available in some way to the user of the browser. Given the limits you have given us, there is no way to do this without making it possible for the users to get the credentials if they so desire.